# bash: sending compressed files while compressing others

Tags: linux, bash

i have a simple bash script to download a lot of logs files over pretty slow network. i can compress logs on the remote side. basically it's:

```
ssh: compress whole directory
scp: download archive
ssh: rm archive
```

using lzma gives great compression but compressing the whole directory is slow. is there any tool or easy way to write a script that allows me to compress a single files (or a bunch of files) and start downloading them while other files/chunks are still being compressed? i was thinking about launching compressing for every single file in the background and in the loop downloading/rsync files with correct extension. but then i don't know how to check if compressing process finished its work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best solution i found [here](https://superuser.com/a/1116247/311798). in my case it was:

```
ssh -T user@example.com 'tar ... | lzma -5 -' > big.compressed
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to compress them in transit using `ssh -C`.  However, if you have a large number of small files, you are better off tarring and gzip/bzipping the whole directory at once using `tar zcf` or `tar jcf`.  You *may* be able to start downloading the file while it's still being written, though I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ssh`ing into your server and going to the log directory and using **GNU Parallel** to compress all the logs in parallel and as each one is compressed, change its name to add the `.done` suffix so you can do `rsync`. So, on the server you would run:

```
cd <LOG DIRECTORY>
rm ALL_COMPRESSED.marker
parallel 'lzma {}; mv {}.lzma {}.lzma.done' ::: *.log
touch ALL_COMPRESSED.marker
```